# Login form throws invalid username or password although username and password is correct

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

I watched a tutorial about Spring Security and tried to write an application with a login form (for admin role). It works fine, but when I try to submit the username and password on the login page it always appears the error message "Invalid username or password" although I had the right ones (from the database).
The error might appear because of the Spring security config, but I don't know exactly the cause. Can someone please help me?

LoginController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
                    @RequestParam (value = "logout", required = false) String logout, Model model) {
    if (error != null) {
        model.addAttribute("error","Invalid username or passwrd");
    }

    if (logout != null ){
        model.addAttribute("msg","you have been logged out successfully");
    }

    return "login";
}
```

login.jsp

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp" %>

<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="login-box">

            <h2>Login with Username and Password</h2>

            <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
                <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
            </c:if>


            <form name="loginForm" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />" method="post">
                <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                    <div class="error" style="color: mediumvioletred ">${error}</div>
                </c:if>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">User: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password: </label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">

                <!--we include the csrf token else the system will reject the form submission  -->
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameter}" value="${_csrf.token}" />

            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp" %>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


    <bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/musicStore?useSSL=false" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.emusicstore</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10254000" />
    </bean>


    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/admin/"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <security:logout
            logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                                        authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, authority FROM authorities WHERE username = ?"
                                        users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users where username = ?" />
        </security:authentication-provider>

    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mywebsite</groupId>
    <artifactId>emusicstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.44</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add dep for upload images-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- the next three should be after spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Request param is a string. So do check for empty string also.

```
if (error != null) {
    model.addAttribute("error","Invalid username or passwrd");
}
```

to

```
if (error != null && !error.isEmpty()) {
    model.addAttribute("error","Invalid username or passwrd");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. But if I add this, it only doesn't show the message "Invalid username or password" (even if I insert something)... And if I insert the right username and passwords, it still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

All solved... The problem was the connection to the database.